# Windows Forms DataVisualization Charting overlapping Series?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I've created a chart for a windows forms project and am trying to use one chart to track two series - essentially collected value and budgeted value. My desired goal would be to have the two series overlap each other in appearance - so if collected was OVER the value of budgeted, you wouldn't even see the bar representing budgeted for that particular value. Unfortunately, I can't seem to achieve this. If I set the charttype to stackedbar, the second series added just seems to be offset, so no matter how large the difference in the two numbers I still see both bars, and if I set the bar type to be bar, the two bars just appear side by side.

Is there a way to achieve what I am aiming for? Am I even thinking about this problem in the right way? I've searched for tutorials on charting, but the ones I've stumbled upon have been pretty basic. Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you may be able to provide.

The relevant code for creating the chart:

```
        string receiptQry = "<sql query text>";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        csb.DataSource = "mysqlserver";
        csb.InitialCatalog = "mydatabase";
        csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        string connString = csb.ToString();
        dt.Columns.Add("AttyCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Collected Receipts", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Budgeted Receipts", typeof(string));
        dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["AttyCode"] };

        List<string> attyList = new List<string>();
        List<string> rcptList = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = receiptQry;

                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        attyList.Add(reader["REF_CODE"].ToString());
                        rcptList.Add(reader["Collected Receipts"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string s in attyList)
        {
            if (rcptList[i].ToString() != "0.00")
            {
                string budgRecp = get_year_budget_rcpts(s.Trim()).ToString();
                AddRow3(dt, s, rcptList[i].ToString(), budgRecp);
            }
            i++;
        }

        chart1.DataSource = dt;

        chart1.Series.Add("Budgeted");
        chart1.Series.Add("Receipts");

        chart1.Series["Receipts"].XValueMember = "AttyCode";
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].XValueMember = "AttyCode";
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].YValueMembers = "Collected Receipts";
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].YValueMembers = "Budgeted Receipts";
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].IsXValueIndexed = true;
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].YValuesPerPoint = 1;
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].IsXValueIndexed = true;
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].YValuesPerPoint = 1;
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chart1.DataBind();

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Attorney Code";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Collected Receipts [YTD]";
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;

        chart1.Series["Receipts"].Color = Color.Green;
        chart1.Series["Budgeted"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series["Receipts"].BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 20;
```